# connecting php 5.2.4 with MSSQL server 2008 using pdo

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I use php 5.2.4, and I am trying to connect with the MSSQL database, without success.
My php info show this:

```
mssql
MSSQL Support   enabled
Active Persistent Links     0
Active Links    0
Library version     7.0 

pdo_mssql
PDO Driver for MSSQL DB-lib enabled
Flavour     MSSQL_70
```

My PHP code is: as follow:

```
$db = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server= servername\sqlservername;Database=mydb", "myuser", "mypass");
var_dump($db);
```

The error message displays:
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'could not find driver'

Anyone have idea what is wrong?

Comment: Heh. Do a phpinfo(), look for pdo_mysql, if it's not there(which it probably isn't) you'll need to install it.

Comment: I did that, please check the title of the question, and the output of my php info above.

Comment: Oh crap, sorry man, dunno where my mind was. Never used MSSQL, but you may want to check out these questions: [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18947480/could-not-find-driver-error-when-using-pdo-with-mssql-server) and [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16310892/mssql-pdo-could-not-find-driver)

Comment: Thanks Andrei, i have already searched for possible answer, I have seen those but didn't work for me. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Try this `$db = new PDO("mssql:host=$host;Database=mydb", "myuser", "mypass");
var_dump($db);` where `$host = $hostname.':'.$port;`