# SQLSRV PHP7 PDO 'driver could not be found' error

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

Im trying to setup PDO to connect to an MSSQL database with XAMPP, I am running PHP 7, ive spent quite alot of time traversing the internet to try and overcome " Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'could not find driver'"
error but so far im having no luck.

The drivers i am using were obtained from: [HERE](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098) (v4.0)

And have installed the Microsoft OCDB driver 13 from: [HERE](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50420)

I have installed Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 aswell but i am still getting the same error, this is what ive tried so far.

I began by downloading the drivers designed for PHP7, i installed them into:
C:\xampp\php\ext

after which i added the extensions into the php.ini file located: C:\xampp\php

extension=php_sqlsrv_7_ts_x64.dll

extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_ts_x64.dll

extension=php_sqlsrv_7_nts_x64.dll

extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_nts_x64.dll

trying both the thread safe and non thread safe.

ive also set the extension_dir to the correct folder.

```
<?php
       $path = php_ini_loaded_file();
       echo 'The loaded file path is :' . $path;
       echo '<br><br>';
       $loadedExt = get_loaded_extensions();
       print_r ($loadedExt);
       $db = new PDO('sqlsrv:host=********;dbname=******;charset=utf8', 'username', 'password');
       $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);  
?>
```

This is the code i am using ^^, upon execution i am given this:

```
The loaded file path is :C:\xampp\php\php.ini

Array ( [0] => Core [1] => bcmath [2] => calendar [3] => ctype [4] => date [5] => ereg [6] => filter [7] => ftp [8] => hash [9] => iconv [10] => json [11] => mcrypt [12] => SPL [13] => odbc [14] => pcre [15] => Reflection [16] => session [17] => standard [18] => mysqlnd [19] => tokenizer [20] => zip [21] => zlib [22] => libxml [23] => dom [24] => PDO [25] => bz2 [26] => SimpleXML [27] => wddx [28] => xml [29] => xmlreader [30] => xmlwriter [31] => apache2handler [32] => openssl [33] => curl [34] => fileinfo [35] => gd [36] => gettext [37] => mbstring [38] => exif [39] => mysql [40] => mysqli [41] => pdo_mysql [42] => pdo_sqlite [43] => Phar [44] => mhash ) 
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'could not find driver' in C:\xampp\htdocs\BasicPDO\index.php:20 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\BasicPDO\index.php(20): PDO->__construct('sqlsrv:host=col...', 'paisjd3', 'Famousrat6') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\BasicPDO\index.php on line 20
```

i am still getting the same error each time ive tried many different solutions to try and overcome this problem but still cant seem to figure this out, im realitively new to php so any help you could provide would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Jack.

EDIT: Still looking for some help with this if anyone can provide any insight it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: if you do phpinfo does sqlsrv show up in the list of extensions?

Comment: have you seen the answer to this question? its a bit old but worth a shot http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18947480/could-not-find-driver-error-when-using-pdo-with-mssql-server?rq=1

Comment: the list of extensions is in the second code block but it does not, i really cant seem to figure out why though.

Comment: @bumperbox ill walkthrough that answer but i have spent many hours searching through stackoverflow

Comment: basically it just said try the 32bit version not 64bit. things may have changed, that was 2013. I have just had an issue with another driver recently that was odbc based and I had to switch back to 32bit, so it may be relevant.

Comment: ill edit with php info in a new code block

Comment: ill look at the 32 bit versions and see if that gives me any luck then

Comment: i have just found {"--without-mssql" "--without-pdo-mssql"} within the configure command could this possibly be my problem?

Comment: I don't think so, mssql is the old driver, you are wanting sqlsrv. if you run php from the cmd line (be aware there is a separate php.ini file usually), and it will spit out errors about the extensions failing. if you fire up php from apache, the errors are not always displayed

Comment: im installing the 32 bit xampp at the moment but im just getting errors on start, let me resolve these

Comment: Ive tried installing the 32 bit version but each time i start the apache server with the extenstions in the ini file i keep getting php7.dll is missing for some odd reason

Comment: ive had to revert back to the 64 bit xampp as the 32 bit will not work correctly and im unables to install 32 bit version of the OCBD Driver

Comment: @Terakin I have same error on php 7.1.12, with php 7.0.16 this drivers start working.